# ioctl and hdreg to get information on harddrives

Tags: c, disk, ioctl, sector

I want to get basic information from a hard-drive and print it out. The most important is that the physical sector size is correct.

For the past few hours I have been fighting with `ioctl` to get what I want but I can't figure it out.

I have never used `ioctl` before and I can't seem to find an easy explanation on what exactly you have to do.

Anyway my code looks something like this

```
int main () {
    FILE *driveptr;
    int sectorsize;
    struct hd_driveid hd;

    driveptr=fopen("/dev/sda","r");

    if (ioctl(driveptr,HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd)!=0) { 
        printf("Hard disk model: %s\n",hd.model); 
        printf("Serial number: %s\n",hd.serial_no); 
        printf("Sector size: %i\n",hd.sector_bytes);
        sectorsize=hd.sector_bytes;
    } else { 
        printf("Error fetching device data.\n");
    }
}
```

In the compiler it throws these warnings, it compiles but the strings are empty when printed.

```
gcc -o test source.c
source.c: In function ‘main’:
source.c:67:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ioctl’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ioctl.h:42:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
```

I hope somebody can explain to me what goes wrong!

Comment: Don't hard disks often lie about their sector size these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (ioctl(driveptr,HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd)!=0) {
```

you probably want

```
if (ioctl(fileno(driveptr),HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd)!= -1) { 
          ^^^^^^^        ^                           ^^
```

Because `ioctl`'s first argument need to be an integer file descriptor not a `FILE *`

`fileno()` will give you an integer fd from a `FILE *`.

Note also that `ioctl` returns -1 on an error and sets errno.

Reading the man pages of the functions you are using is probably quicker than posting to StackOverflow.

See man pages of [ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html), [fileno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno).

Comment: thx that works!! short question, do you know if that is the 'real' physical sector size or rather the logical sector size. I read online that using (ioctl(fileno(driveptr),BLKSSZGET, &sectorsize) is the most accurate way. but it throws numbers like 60k to me.

Comment: You can also replace your FILE* variable with an int (a file descriptor) and invoke open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY) instead of fopen("/dev/sda", "r"). That way, you don't have to invoke fileno() to convert the stream to a file descriptor.